# How to set up job accounting for a Kyocera M6030cdn printer on a Mac

Tags: printing, printer

I'm trying to follow the [manual](https://cdn.kyostatics.net/dlc/eu/documentation/usermanual/ecosys_m6030cdn_m6530cdn2.-downloadcenteritem-Single-File.downloadcenteritem.tmp/ECOSYS_M6030cdn...dn_OG_(ENG).pdf) to set up Job Accounting on a Kyocera M6030cdn printer using a Mac. I've installed what I believe is the correct driver:

[image]

and I'm running MacOS Sierra. However, if I then go to System Settings > Printers & Scanners and select the printer, I don't see a "Job Accounting" tab among the Options as in the example shown for Windows (see screenshots below).

How can I configure the Job Accounting?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't find the 6030, but the manual for the Ecosys 6530 may help. See https://usa.kyoceradocumentsolutions.com/content/dam/kdc/kdag/downloads/technical/documentation/manuals/kyoceradocumentsolutions/us/en/MacDriver3SoftwareGuide1.1.pdf from pg 13.

Answer (score 1):

Open Kyocera Print Panel (you can open this through spotlight — command+space), select your printer, click on "Job" on the left side, and you can enter your account ID after you check the box under "Job Accounting."